# Allow dismissing duplicate documentation request pointing to another request

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Right now if you want to dismiss a topic request with a reason "already exists", you need to link to an existing topic.

Because of that, you can't get rid of duplicate requests by pointing them to other requests that are yet to be fulfilled.